# What legal actions can we take for website that doesn't remove PII upon requests?

Tags: copyright, internet, data-protection, personal-information

A business directory listing website scraped old data for their listings. They use random contact information, personally identifiable information (PII), logos/banners to falsely represent those business listings and individuals.

That directory listing website presents itself as a self submission service but those listings are listed without owners permissions and valid contact information.

Simply, that directory listing website is just to generate impressions for ads revenue. The contact info stated on their website is invalid.

What legal actions can an individual take to have the listing that contains PII to be removed from such directory website? Does the use of random banners/logos to misrepresent those listings have any copyright infringement issues?

-- Added Info ---

- Based on a search, the directory website should be hosted at Deutschland.
- It scraped data from all over the world. It has a very huge database of domains(active and expired) but most of the information is invalid.
- It looks more like a bogus directory website than anything. The last edit of privacy policy was in early 2018 in which the operation is different from what it claims. The listed contact information is invalid too.

Are there anything to be done in this scenario?

Comment: Where is the website hosted? Where are the people whose PII is listed located? Does the GDPR or another data protection law apply? Please edit the question to add this info.

Comment: Are you sure the information was invalid in 2018? it's entirely possible that the website's company stopped in 2018 and its domain is prepaid till years later and just remains in its old state till the domain expires.

Comment: @Trish I'm not sure which information you are referring to? A live website requires not only domain but also hosting. Anyway, the domain is renewed in 2022.

Comment: Websites can be bought long contract wise, just like hosting. People own websites and forgot they even exist still. Companies have been dissolved for years but their bank account - abandoned but not properly closed - might still pay recurring fees for several years. Automatic renewal does not take any action in case the registrar and hoster can just debit the existing account or the account was filled with money for later use.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, you allege the website is actively looking for information *now*. But you also allege the website was last updated about 2018. Which might be the last time the site ever was current and the information would have been correct in 2018.

Comment: @Trish Thanks but you have quoted a less common scenario which is difficult to relate to. Not to mention it is a revenue generating site. Did I mention the site or privacy policy was last updated in 2018? Which part of my post has given the impression that it is *actively looking for information now*? In your first comment, what information you are referring to?

Comment: You allege the information is *wrong* or *deloibareately wrong*. Can it be just *outdated*?!

Comment: @Trish Whether it is deliberately wrong, I am not sure but I don't think so. I certainly don't think the listings are outdated when majority of them are absolutely invalid. I will not say ALL listings are invalid because I have not clicked on every single listing to verify. Please advise how this will make any difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

> What legal actions can an individual take to have the listing that
> contains PII to be removed from such directory website?

You can take action under the [UK GDPR](https://uk-gdpr.org/).

Assumptions:

- The processing falls within the territorial scope in [Article 3](https://uk-gdpr.org/territorial-scope/).
- The data falls within the definition of "personal data" under [Article 4(1)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-1-article-4/).
- The controller doesn't have any of the six lawful bases for processing the personal data under [Article 6(1)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-2-article-6/).

In that case you have the right to require the controller to erase the data under [Article 17](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-3-article-17/). [Article 12](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-3-article-12/) contains details of how controllers must handle such requests.

The request would most likely be made under Article 17(1)(d) i.e. that the controller never had a lawful basis to process the data in the first place. Alternatives include Article 17(1)(a) (the controller had a lawful basis but the processing is no longer necessary under that basis) or Article 17(1)(b) (the only lawful basis was consent and you are withdrawing your consent).

Under Article 12(3) the following deadlines apply for the controller to action your request:

1. The controller must *always* action it *without undue delay*.
2. Even if the controller can justify a delay, there is an upper time limit of 1 month.
3. That can be extended to 2 months for complex requests provided that you are notified within 1 month.
4. The clock can be paused under Article 12(6) if the controller has reasonable doubts about your identity and requests further information from you.

After the applicable deadline has passed, you have two options:

1. Complain to the regulator under [Article 77](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-77/). In the UK the regulator is the ICO and you can make a complaint [here](https://ico.org.uk/make-a-complaint). Under [Article 58](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-6-article-58/), the ICO can, among other powers, order the controller to erase the data. It can also impose a fine of up to £17,500,000 or 4% of annual turnover under [Article 83(5)](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-83/). Complaining to the ICO is often preferred as it is free and without risk to the complainant.
2. Seek an injunction in the courts under [Article 79](https://uk-gdpr.org/chapter-8-article-79/). That is done by applying to the County Court for a compliance order under Sections [167](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12/section/167) and [180(1)(a)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/12/section/180) of the Data Protection Act 2018. If you go down this route you will have to pay court fees which you may not recover if you lose. You may also risk paying the other party's costs.

Very similar rules apply to the EU. The main difference is that you need to look at the [EU GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) instead of the UK GDPR.

Comment: Thank you! That's very informative and helpful!